# How to resolve Exception Error in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am in the process of converting an older DOS based 16-bit application into a current Windows console app. Each time I run the application in debug mode I receive the following error:

```
Project xxxx.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x004151f9: read of address 0x00000000'.
```

The following is the code line that blows up:

```
if ((argc < 1) || (strcmp(argv[1],"/?")) == 0) prg_syntax();
```

The code evaluates and should run the function to display the programs syntax but doesn't and instead throws the error.

I am using C++ Builder version (11.1.5).

Any help of where or how to overcome I would greatly appreciate.

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: Pop quiz: if `argc` has the value of 1, what do you expect to be in `argv[1]`, and why? This is a trick question, there is no `argv[1]` in that case.

Comment: *I am in the process of converting an older DOS based 16-bit application into a current Windows console app.* -- If that was the actual code for the 16-bit application, the app was broken from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the convention argc cannot be lower than 1, because it will have at least the name / symbolic link to the execution (binary) file. In the case of no arguments passed to your program it will try to deference NULL pointer (the last element of argv[]).

```
  if ((1 < 1) || (strcmp(NULL,"/?")) == 0) prg_syntax();
```

I believe you've wanted to do something like this:

```
  if ((argc < 2) || (strcmp(argv[1],"/?")) == 0) prg_syntax();
```

Comment: _"The argc cannot be lower than 1"_ - is wrong so perhaps don't include that.

Comment: `argv[0]` ***usually*** holds the executable's name/path, but that is not ***guaranteed***.  It is *possible* to spawn a process in such a way that the executable's name/path is not present on the command-line string that gets parsed into `argv`. But, you have to go out of your way to accomplish that, it won't happen that way if you just launch the executable "normally" 99.9999% of the time.

Comment: It amazing that the old BC compiler never caught this error and everything seemed to work just fine. Thanks everyone much appreciated.